# How to emit an object after X seconds?

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2, system.reactive

I have Observable.just("Hello") but I'd like to emit this after X seconds. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `Timer()` fucnction, like this:

```
Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(X)).Select(_ => "Hello")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Delay](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/delay.html) operator:

> shift the emissions from an Observable forward in time by a particular amount
>   delay
>
> The Delay operator modifies its source Observable by pausing for a particular increment of time (that you specify) before emitting each of the source Observable’s items. This has the effect of shifting the entire sequence of items emitted by the Observable forward in time by that specified increment.

The snippet below is taken from [this blog](https://blog.mindorks.com/understanding-rxjava-timer-delay-and-interval-operators)

```java
Observable.create<String> { emitter ->
    Log.d("DelayExample", "Create")
    emitter.onNext("MindOrks")
    emitter.onComplete()
}
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.delay(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe {
    Log.d("DelayExample", it)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Observable.timer`

> Returns an Observable that emits `0L` after a specified delay, and then completes.
>
> The operates by default on the `computation` scheduler

You can do

```
Observable.timer(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .map(t -> "Hello")
```

If your source is not simply value but `Observable`, you can do

```
Observable<String> source = Observable.just("Hello");
Observable.timer(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .concatMap(t -> source);
```